# Getting last item in groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have found a few answers on here which I have followed, found it working locally so I pushed up to our test-box where I'm finding this specific DB queries lasts over 1300 seconds by going in to mysql and `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and it's hanging on `copying to tmp table`

It's Laravel 4.2, pretty old legacy code which I'm just trying to stabalise whilst working on a later version. This code below repeats roughly every 30  seconds as per the api_call, which is all well and good except it's not finishing and receiving a `504 Gateway Time-out` I feel like I'm doing something recursive or would scouring a really large database be an issue here?

All I’m trying to do is run a groupBy but instead of grouping by the first one I want to group by the last one, just in case of other details being updated.

Any help provided would be highly appreciated.

```
public function api_prevnames()
{
    if (Auth::user()->repeat_vistor == 'Y') {
        $names = DB::table('visitors')
            ->select(DB::raw('first_name,last_name,email,car_reg,OPTIN,vistor_company'))
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('hidden', 0)
            ->where('email', '<>', '')
            ->whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM visitors GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email)')
            ->get();
    }

    return JSONResponseGenerator::successResponse($names->toArray());

}
```

Which generates this query

```
select first_name,last_name,email,car_reg,OPTIN,vistor_company from `visitors` where `user_id` = '439' and `hidden` = '0' and `email` <> '' and id IN (select MAX(id) FROM visitors GROUP BY first_name, last_name, email)
```

The previous code runs in just under a couple seconds which I've added below:

```
            $names = DB::table('visitors')
            ->select(DB::raw('first_name,last_name,email,car_reg,OPTIN,vistor_company'))
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('hidden', 0)
            ->where('email', '<>', '')
            ->groupBy('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run the following:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    car_reg,
    OPTIN,
    vistor_company
FROM (
    SELECT
        MAX(id) AS id
    FROM `visitors`
    WHERE
        `user_id` = 439
        AND `hidden` = 0
        AND `email` <> ''
    GROUP BY
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email
) AS subQ
NATURAL JOIN `visitors`;
```

Joins usually are faster than the other way around but I don't think it will help because you apparently are not grouping by indexes. To do that you would have to change the structure and I highly recommend doing so. Try to reduce the maximum length of first_name, last_name and email, so you can create a combined index of these three. If you can change the database structure itself without killing half your system, you should consider to normalize this table like having a table with visitors and another one with visits of those visitors (relation with foreign keys), so you can group by a key instead of grouping by three unindexed strings with a big length.

Comment: [Here is an imgur of the table/query](https://imgur.com/a/wv2F7Sv) I've also added the text query above.

Comment: Absolutely smashed it mate, does exactly what I needed it to and quite fast too!

Comment: I've updated your edit to add in the exact process I did to fix this within Laravel. Really appreciate your help.